# Python XPath parsing tag with apostrophe

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, apostrophe

I'm new to XPath. I'm trying to parse a page using XPath. I need to get information from  tag, but escaped apostrophe in title screws up everything.

For parsing i use [Grab](http://packages.python.org/grab/).

tag from source:

```
<img src='somelink' border='0' alt='commission:Alfred\'s misadventures' title='commission:Alfred\'s misadventures'>
```

Actual XPath:

```
g.xpath('.//tr/td/a[3]/img').get('title')
```

Returns

```
commission:Alfred\\
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, you should be glad your `.xpath` returns anything. This HTML is invalid enough for LXML's `html` module to choke on it.

Comment: I just did some experimenting with lxml and BeautifulSoup, and neither of them parsed it correctly, either. Obviously, the outer quotes for the attribute values should be double quotes. What is the source of the html?

Answer (score 5):

Garbage in, garbage out. Your input is not well-formed, because it improperly escapes the single quote character. Many programming languages (including Python) use the backslash character to escape quotes in string literals. XML does not. You should either 1) surround the attribute's value with double-quotes; or 2) **use `&apos;` to include a single quote**.

From [the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax):

> To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes,
>   the apostrophe or single-quote character (') may be represented as "
>   `&apos;` ", and the double-quote character (") as " `&quot;` ".

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it's not my input. I'm trying to parse a page with that tag, so only way to fix this - replace it in whole source. Gladly, i've already solved ( not exactly, but anyways... ) this problem with regex

Comment: XML breaks Postel's law, but in practice it's sometimes necessary to massage the input before sending it to a proper XML parser. Some purists will berate you for it, but I wouldn't feel too bad about it.

Comment: XML already allows TWO methods of getting an apostrophe into an attribute value: (1) enclose the value in quotes instead of apostrophes (2) use. `&apos;`. Let's make it Postel-compliant, and add two extra methods. (1) backslash-escaping (2) apostrophe-doubling, as in SQL. Your tasks: update the grammar, enhance a parser. Alternative: Be glad that XML has avoided the HTML shambles where consumers go out of their way to accept bad HTML.

Comment: Consumers will always go out of their way to accept bad input, because to do otherwise is to punish users over an esoteric technical argument they care nothing about.

Answer (score 2):

**As the provided "XML" isn't a wellformed document due to nested apostrophes, no XPath expression can be evaluated on it**.

The provided non-well-formed text can be corrected to:

```
<img src="somelink"
 border="0"
 alt="commission:Alfred's misadventures"
 title="commission:Alfred's misadventures"/>
```

**In case there is a weird requiremend not to use quotes, then one correct convertion is**:

```
<img src='somelink'
 border='0'
 alt='commission:Alfred&apos;s misadventures'
 title='commission:Alfred&apos;s misadventures'/>
```

**If you are provided the incorrect input, in a language such as C# one can try to convert it to its correct counterpart using**:

```
string correctXml = input.replace("\\'s", "&apos;s")
```

Probably there is a similar way to do the same in Python.